# Is it not a good Idea to use the Set Worksheets method multiple times during code execution?

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am attempting to copy different images to different worksheets of my Workbook using the following code below. I am changing the Target Worksheet Dynamically in a different sub, with a String Variable in the Global Declarations section. I can see the variable being passed to the sub and in fact it works the first pass through the code, but when I attempt to change the "`TargetSheetIni`" variable to a new sheet, it continues to use the first original sheet as it loops through.

Can you not change a target sheet after using the `Set` keyword? Should I refer to the sheet directly instead?

```
Sub Test1()

Dim TargetWS, SourceWS As Worksheet

Set TargetWS = Worksheets(TargetSheetIni)
Set SourceWS = Worksheets("Images")

DoEvents
SourceWS.Shapes(CurrentImageId).Copy
DoEvents
TargetWS.Paste Range(ColumnLetter2 & RwCnter)
DoEvents

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Where do you set the worksheet name variable?

Comment: You can use Set whereever and as often as you like: there's no restriction.  What you should do though is qualify explicitly which *workbook* the sheet you want is in.  That avoids confusion when you have multiple workbooks open. So `Set TargetWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheetIni)` or `Set TargetWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TargetSheetIni)` for example.  If you're running Set and it has no effect, then maybe you're using `On Error Resume Next` in your code?

Comment: You can use `Set` multiple times. That's not the cause of your problem. You haven't shown enough of your code to figure out where your problem lies.  But you may need to define the worksheet object variables globally, not the name string.

Comment: Thanks Everyone for your responses so far! I have moved the Worksheet Declaration to the global section of the module. Should I being using a Module or should code like this live in the "ThisWorkbook" Section instead? I have also added the "ThisWorkbook" designation to my set statement, but I am pretty sure that is not the issue. As I only have one workbook open when I run the code, but probably a good practice to do this just in case. As to the other code missing. Its a pretty big sub so I wanted to only include what is relevant. but...

Comment: ' Sub SheetChooser()
 
 For i = 1 To 4
  TargetSheetIni = "Sheet" & i
 Call test1
 
 Next i
 
End Sub ' is the jist of it

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured it out. As far as I can tell the issue may be that I used the Copy Sheet Functionality in Excel when I originally created the target sheets. And even though I renamed the sheets both on the tab below and in the project editor... for some reason VBA kept targeting only the original sheet

I proved this by changing my code around to explicitly call the sheet I wanted to target like so:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Paste Range("I2")
```

And even doing that it would target sheet 1 for the paste command instead of the expected sheet 2. I deleted the three copy sheets and created a new one from scratch and re-executed code and now it targets sheet 2 as expected.

I found this article that sort of explains it I guess...

https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/7-common-vba-mistakes-to-avoid/

Answer (score 0):

Ok my last answer may have not been correct. It appears as though for some reason inserting an ws.activate caused my code to start workin.g
Very frustrating fix. as I have always heard to avoid using that.